# Creating space between table elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a gap between text and an image for an HTML email. However, I cannot seem to move the image down no matter what I've tried.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rwcgs0g8/

I want the red "Download your free" image to simply move down by 5px.

I have tried adding add `<td height="10"><!-- PADDING --></td>` before the image (and after the ipsum text), but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It's 2017, please stop using tables for layout!

Comment: what you are trying to achieve, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Put an [mcve] **in your question**

Answer (score 0):

Change style of that image to `style="display:block;margin-top:5px;"`

Or 
Put up a div between text and image. Div is a blocking html element.

```
 <div style="height:5px">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately margins are not recommended for HTML emails.

Comment: You can put a div between text and image

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
margin-top: 5px;
```

to the image's CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately margins are not recommended for HTML emails.

Comment: In that case, you could insert <div style="height: 5px;"></div> above the image.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#0066cb">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td height="240" width="15"><!-- PADDING (CREATING AREA) --></td>
  <td>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <tbody>
    <tr><td height="10"><!-- PADDING --></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
      <!-- IMAGE  -->
                        <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2z3tc0w.png" alt="img1" height="250"  style="display:block;" border="0" />
     </td>
     <td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:27px;line-height:35px;color:#ffffff;">
                    <p style="padding-bottom: 5px;margin: 0;">
                        eguide title lorum ipsum <br/>
      dolor sit amet labore etJavaScript
                    </p>
     <img src="https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/08/22/unnamed5.png" alt="img2"   style="display:block;" border="0" />
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table> 
 <!-- END OF SECTION 2 -->            
 </td> 
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```
<p style="padding-bottom: 5px;margin: 0;">
  eguide title lorum ipsum <br/>
  dolor sit amet labore etJavaScript
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately margins are not recommended for HTML emails.

Comment: @Freddy I used padding. Using padding also is not recommended?